# jQuery.msgBox() plugin. How to send data to /users/login to login user

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

I am trying to use the following jQuery plugin ([jQuery.msgBox()](http://jquerymsgbox.ibrahimkalyoncu.com/)) to perform login to a CakePHP site, but I am confused on how I need to submit the data to my php function for login and redirect if login successful or display a message if not successful. I would appreciate any help.

This is the jQuery function I am using to display the hidden login box, when a user presses the INSERT key on the keyboard.

```
jQuery(document).bind('keydown', 'insert', function(e) {
    //alert(e.keyCode);
        $.msgBox({
            type: "prompt",
            title: "Administrator Log In",
            opacity: 0.7,
            inputs: [
                { header: "User Name", type: "text", name: "username" },
                { header: "Password", type: "password", name: "password" },
                //{ header: "Remember me", type: "checkbox", name: "rememberMe", value: "theValue" }
    ],
            buttons: [
                { value: "Login" }, {value:"Cancel"}],
            success: function (result, values) {
                var v = result + " has been clicked\n";
                $(values).each(function (index, input) {
                    v += input.name + " : " + input.value + 
                    (input.checked != null ? (" - checked: " + input.checked) : "") + "\n";         
                });
                alert(v); // for testing purposes. Insert login code below
                // =======================================================

                // =======================================================
            }
        });     
});
```

I ENDED UP CHANGING vortextangent'S ANSWER A LITTLE BIT, BUT IT WAS BASED ON HIS ANSWER. SEE BELOW.....

=========================================================================================

```
        jQuery(document).bind('keydown', 'insert', function(e) {
    //alert(e.keyCode);
        $.msgBox({
            type: "prompt",
            title: "Administrator Log In",
            opacity: 0.7,
            inputs: [
                { header: "User Name", type: "text", name: "data[User][username]" },
                { header: "Password", type: "password", name: "data[User][password]" },
                //{ header: "Remember me", type: "checkbox", name: "rememberMe", value: "theValue" }
    ],
            buttons: [
                { value: "Login" }, {value:"Cancel"}],
            success: function (result, values) {
                var v = result + " has been clicked\n";
                $(values).each(function (index, input) {
                    v += input.name + " : " + input.value + 
                    (input.checked != null ? (" - checked: " + input.checked) : "") + "\n";         
                });
                //alert(v);
        $.ajax({
        url: "/users/login",
        type: "post",
        data: values,
        success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form){ // Trigger when request was successful
            //responseLogin
            if(responseText == "Success")   {
            window.location.href = '/users/account';
            }else{
            //alert("Wrong credentials. Please try again...");
            $.msgBox({
                title: "Login Error",
                content: "Wrong credentials. Please try again...",
                type: "error",
                buttons: [{ value: "Ok" }]
            });
            }
        }
        });
            }
        });     
});
```

=========================================================================================

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jQuery ajax method.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
jQuery(document).bind('keydown', 'insert', function(e) {
//alert(e.keyCode);
    $.msgBox({
        type: "prompt",
        title: "Administrator Log In",
        opacity: 0.7,
        inputs: [
            { header: "User Name", type: "text", name: "username" },
            { header: "Password", type: "password", name: "password" },
            //{ header: "Remember me", type: "checkbox", name: "rememberMe", value: "theValue" }
],
        buttons: [
            { value: "Login" }, {value:"Cancel"}],
        success: function (result, values) {
            var v = result + " has been clicked\n";
            $(values).each(function (index, input) {
                v += input.name + " : " + input.value + 
                (input.checked != null ? (" - checked: " + input.checked) : "") + "\n";         
            });
            alert(v); // for testing purposes. Insert login code below
            // =======================================================
            $.ajax({
                url: "yourloginscript.php",
                type: "post",
                data: values,
                success: function(){ // Trigger when request was successful
                    window.location.href = 'somewhere'
                },
                error: function(request, error, errormessage) { // Show error
                    $("#error").html(error + '\n' + errormessage);
                },
                complete: otherFunction // When request is completed -no matter if the error or not
            });
            // =======================================================
        }
    });     
});
```